# Does a Google Apps Script exist to unprotect a range of cells at a specific date?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a Google spreadsheet, I created what is basically a calendar that other users are able to populate events using a drop down menu. However, I only want them to be able to populate this calendar up to 2 weeks in advance.

I'm wondering if there is an apps script that exist to do this and where I would be able to find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're asking for references to offsite resources, that's off-topic. If you want help with your code, you need to post it.Please read this [advice on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to follow the link at the bottom to Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Apps Script currently doesn't provide the ability to manipulate the range protection in a spreadsheet. Follow [issue 1721](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1721) for updates on when this feature is available.